# How to know if a mac is under DEP (Device Enrollment Program)?

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, automated-device-enrollment

I just bought a used macbook air 2015
I made a system restore... and was confident the mac is not stolen because of these checks

1- there were no icloud on the computer, and I was able to add my own iCloud normally.

2- the mac firmware had no password

but now, I see something that I have never seen before

I keep seeing this message, always skipping it

[image]

1- what are the consequences of allowing DEP, and is it reversible?

2- how to contact the person who has DEP and ask them to remove it from the program?

3- when buying a new mac, how to know if it's on DEP? (the most important question)

4- someone on IRC said that if i was unable to authorize my machine from itunes then the machine is on DEP.. is this correct?

5- the same person on IRC says that there could be a previous owner, and this owner can format my computer and see all of my files even if i have my own icloud on it, is this correct?

the person who sold it to me imported 60 macs from a closed startup in sweden, I can return it to the seller and get my money back, but I really need an answer for these questions...

Comment: I read almost everything online.

Comment: Please try one question per question. The only way a serial number gets enrolled in DEP is by purchasing from a business/enterprise channel. Working with them or Apple directly is the fastest way to tracing each suspect serial number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen Apple's [DEP FAQ](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204142)? It says

> Which devices can be enrolled in DEP?
>
> Any Apple Mac or iOS devices purchased on or after March 1, 2011 can
>   be enrolled in DEP. Mac or iOS devices purchased from participating
>   Apple Authorized resellers or carriers must be added to your DEP
>   instance to be included. All iOS devices must use iOS 7 or later, and
>   all Mac computers must have OS X Mavericks v10.9 or later. Once
>   configured, automatic enrollment in MDM occurs at the time of device
>   activation if a profile has been assigned. If a device has already
>   been deployed (activated), you can trigger automatic MDM enrollment by
>   erasing and restoring the device.

1. what are the consequences of allowing DEP, and is it reversible?

> DEP supervises and enrolls the device into your Meraki MDM. Any
>   configuration profiles are going to come from Meraki, not DEP. If
>   there are configuration profiles that you want to remove, make the
>   change in Meraki... either remove the device from the "Clients in
>   scope" list under the profile, or remove the profile completely from >Meraki (if you don't want it on any device).
>
> DEP allows for the changing of the following: App Lock (Single App Mode)
>
> Global HTTP Proxy
>
> Activation Lock Bypass
>
> Autonomous Single App Mode
>
> Web Content Filter
>
> Set background & lock screen
>
> Silent App Push
>
> Always-On VPN
>
> Allow managed app installation exclusively
>
> Additionally, you can block/disallow:
>
> iBookstore
>
> iMessages
>
> Game center
>
> AirDrop
>
> AirPlay
>
> Host pairing
>
> Cloud Sync
>
> Spotlight internet results
>
> Handoff
>
> Erase
>
> Restrictions UI
>
> Installation of configuration profiles by UI
>
> News
>
> Keyboard shortcuts
>
> Passcode modifications
>
> Device name changes
>
> Wallpaper changes
>
> Automatic app downloads
>
> Changes to enterprise app trust
>
> Apple Music
>
> Mail Drop

2. how to contact the person who has DEP and ask them to remove it from the program?

> The line under "add to enrollment" will tell you who is running the
>   DEP. You may see details by clicking add, and it will bring up
>   preferences. Under this, you may read (in plaintext) who is trying to
>   enroll you, and you may find out who it is.

3. When buying a new mac, how to know if it's on DEP? (the most important question)

> Reset it. See if it bypasses Setup.

4. Someone on IRC said that if i was unable to authorize my machine from itunes then the machine is on DEP.. is this correct?

> Yes. It would bypass this under MDM or under a DEP.

5. The same person on IRC says that there could be a previous owner, and this owner can format my computer and see all of my files even if i have my own icloud on it, is this correct?

> This is true.
>
> The Device Enrollment Program enables IT to easily leverage the
>   advanced capabilities of supervision without the need to physically
>   tether a device to a master computer running Apple Configurator –
>   supervision can be turned on with the click of a button OTA. IT also
>   benefits from the avoided risks associated with unmanaged devices.
>   With the Device Enrollment Program, IT can leverage un-removable MDM
>   profiles and even require devices to re-enroll after being wiped or
>   reset.

Best of Luck!

Comment: I have already read this, thanks :) , but my questions are still not answered, can you answer each question individually ?

Comment: Answer of fourth question is not clear