# What are the typical changes pushed to Macs when you enroll your own device to a company?

Tags: time-machine, filevault, automated-device-enrollment

I have recently enrolled my Mac to a company that I am working with. After the enrollment the performance of the machine drastically degraded.

When I decided to un-enroll, I contacted the helpdesk and their suggestion was to save the necessary documents and go back in the time machine. Which I did not like as a method.

Now I am trying to understand what has been pushed to the machine so that I can check and rollback them one by one.

Up to now what I have figured was some profiles and the filevault disc encryption.

Other than these two what kind of things are typically pushed to Macs when a machine is enrolled to a company?

PS: As of now the profile status shows DEP as No.

```
MB-22F1FWW4:~ mehmetkaplan$ profiles status -type enrollment
Enrolled via DEP: No
MDM enrollment: No
```

Comment: The answer to [How to know if a mac is under DEP (Device Enrollment Program)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282332/how-to-know-if-a-mac-is-under-dep-device-enrollment-program) provides links to Apple's documentation and provides a list of what is controlled by DEP/MDM environments. Hopefully this will be a good starting point.

Comment: One method we used years ago was to tag all the files in relevant folders with one color, then any new additions would be obvious...